# Particle emitter is intersecting bounding boxfaces

Tags: modeling, particles

I am trying to configure a mesh as a bounding box to generate particles completely inside a given mesh without sticking through the 'bounding' faces.

As an example: the left cube has a volume emitter with objects sticking through the faces.
I would like the particle objects to NOT intersect the bounding mesh. (also in case of more complex objects)

The preferred method I'd like to know would result in a box with no objects intersecting it's faces what so ever.(right cube)

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68389/28015

Comment: I'm not so much worried about self intersecting as much as the emitter geometry sticking through the bounded box or custom object.