# Set minimum distance between hair particles

Tags: particles

I have a mesh with a hair particle system, with mesh objects as hair particles. As you can see in the image below, some of the objects intersect with eachother.

[image]

I would like to set a minimum distance between the hair particles so they don't intersect anymore, but I can't find any way to achieve this.

Comment: I have tried to do this before, and I don't think it is possible. Would love to have this feature, though, because there are so many potential applications!

Comment: If you are making water droplets, I would try using meta balls for the particles. I don't know if it will work, but, it would be good to try it.

Comment: It's not for droplets. I want to place trees on a map without them intersecting eachother

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36892/how-to-use-emitter-for-generating-thick-forest-so-that-trees-would-not-intersect

Comment: @lemon definitely related, but a different question.

Comment: i had a similar problem a while ago, didn't find any solution nor did I get any suggestions on how to solve/work around this. See my question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60587/particle-emitter-is-intersecting-bounding-boxfaces.

Seems like a lot of people wants this option but nobody knows how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After researching a bit further, it looks like this is not a built-in feature for Blender. Although there are some workarounds to *sort of* achieve the effect that have been mentioned in the comments, the solution seems to be an add-on:

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?233643-Addon-Moleculars-physics

http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/

Here is a quick GIF of me doing particle collision with the add-on (I am on a Mac, so I am using an older version):

[image]

This question is very similar:

[How to correct collision between particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5615/28015)